# substitute value from another row where value matches on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this:

```
   INV  AMOUNT     Match
1   A   36.85      NaN
2   B   289.84     NaN
3   C   -96.75     B
4   D   -36.85     A
```

I want to substitute the value of the AMOUNT column, With the absolute value of AMOUNT where MATCH is the same as INV.

It should look like this, only row 2 should change.

```
   INV  AMOUNT     Match
1   A   36.85      NaN
2   B   *96.75*    NaN
3   C   -96.75     B
4   D   -36.85     A
```

Put another way,

If I have df1:

```
   INV  AMOUNT     
1   A   36.85     
2   B   289.84    
3   C   -96.75   
4   D   -36.85
```

and df2:

```
    Match   MONEY
1   NaN     36.85
2   NaN     289.84
3   A       -96.75
4   B       -36.85
```

Substitute the AMOUNT of df1 with the absolute value of MONEY column from df2, where the INV matches with the Match column from df2.

df1 should look like:

```
   INV  AMOUNT     
1   A   36.85     
2   B   96.75    
3   C   -96.75   
4   D   -36.85
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to merge two dataframes

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='AMOUNT', right_on='MONEY').drop('MONEY',axis=1)
```

two dataframes will be merged at all positions where "MONEY" and "AMOUNT" abs values is same and the drop function will drop the common column for you